# How to add controls in tab that generated in run time

Tags: c#, winforms

Am using a tab control and I inserted a list view in that. 
Now I want generate tab while running my program and each tab should contain this listview.

I tried like this:

```
public void FillTabControls(TabControl tb, string sSQL, string sTable, string sFirstItem)
{
    long totalRow = 0;
    //Set the Data Adapter
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, CN);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, sTable);

    totalRow = ds.Tables[sTable].Rows.Count - 1;

    tb.TabPages.Clear();
    if (sFirstItem != "") tb.TabPages.Add(new TabPage(sFirstItem));
    for (int i = 0; i <= totalRow; i++) 
        tb.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("" + ds.Tables[sTable].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString()));
    if (tb.TabPages.Count > 0) 
        tb.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

But am not getting the idea to do this

Answer (score 0):

I think the tab page is getting added. But i dont see where  you are adding the list view. i guess because of which you are not able to visually recognize it.

Also set the size or dock of tab page being added inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
    private IEnumerable<TabPage> GetTabPages(string sSQL, string sTable, string sFirstItem)
    {
        // generate your tabs here
    }

    private void Init(TabControl tb, string sSQL, string sTable, string sFirstItem)
    {
        tb.SuspendLayout();

        foreach (TabPage tabPage in GetTabPages(sSQL, sTable, sFirstItem))
        {
            tb.Controls.Add(tabPage);
        }

        tb.ResumeLayout();
    }
```